# What is the difference between 'related'/'relation' and 'associated'/'association'

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I am coming to this from a very technical background. I am basically trying to figure out when to use which of those terms to describe the associations/relations between classes in an UML class diagram or between entities in a domain model and such things.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_model

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say, in this context (UML), that ***association***, composition and agregation are "subtypes" of ***relationships*** between classes.

This link may be helpful to you 'UML Class Diagram: Association, Aggregation and Composition' : http://aviadezra.blogspot.com.es/2009/05/uml-association-aggregation-composition.html

So, I would use the term ***association*** when refering to the "Association" relationship and ***relationship*** when referencing, in general terms, to the different types of relationship.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very specialised technical area, we can't appeal to conventional English usage rather we need to read the detailed UML specifications and tutorial material.

You might find [this reference](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/association.html) useful.

I agree with (Commander) SamuelVimes comments, that Relationships are more general, Associations being a special kind of Relationship. This is seen in the UML diagrams; we show many kinds of Relationships with different lines, associations have the diamond shape on the end of the line.

So, once you have got a diagram you may relatively easily determine what to say, the hard part is probably making the choices when drawing the diagrams.

Comment: "we can't appeal to conventional English"; Ok. As I am not a native English speaker, can I nevertheless just ask this: Am I correct in assuming that a "relation" (e.g. between 2 persons) is a stronger kind of link than an "association"?

Comment: Ok, I just realize that my concept of "relation" might be skewed. Technical, e.g. a "relative" measurement, and conventional (e.g. a romantic relation) usage indeed seem to differ greatly here.

Comment: Even in standard English it's complicated. I refer to my extended family as my relations or relatives. I can also be "in a relationship" with someone, this implies romance. I have a business relationship with someone implying a formal commercial interaction. Generally as you say associations are weaker, but in the business context my associates are in some sense my partners and so are actually quite close.

Answer (score 0):

"Associated with" infers more intimacy than "related to". If two things are associated with each other it means they are more closely tied together. If they are related to each other it means they share certain common features.